# List all products and count the male users, female users that did not place an Order

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the count of Male and Female users that did not place any order for a product. The result should show all the products and the number of male or female users that did not place any order.

I want the query results to look like this:

```
productid | productName      | No_MaleUsers | No_FemaleUsers|
------------------------------------------------------------
1         | Jeans            |     4       |       4        |
------------------------ -----------------------------------
2         |  Apple Watch     |     4        |       4       |
-------------------------------------------------------------
3         |A pair of socks   |     5        |       4       |
-------------------------------------------------------------
4         |A pair of sneakers|     6        |       4       |
```

---

```
5         | Fast red car     |     6        |       4       |
```

---

```
6         | Macbook          |     6        |       4       |
```

---

Here is a Sample fiddle to help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a0e30

In the Fiddle: User 1 and user 2 are the only ones that placed orders for products uid_1(1,2) and uid_2(1,2,3) and they are males. The remaining users did not place any order.
Update: I've updated my query to show what the final results should look like showing the male and female users that did not make place any orders

Comment: quite a few queries, but no good results

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Totally 6 males user  and 2 bought Jeans shouldn't the `No_MaleUsers` be 4

Comment: @Prdp i've updated my answer to reflect the expeted results. apologies for the initial incomplete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complicated query.  One approach is to use correlated subqueries:

```
select p.*,
       (select count(*)
        from users u 
        where u.uid not in (select o.uid from orders o where o.productid = p.productid) and 
              u.gender = 'Male'
       ) as NumMales,
       (select count(*)
        from users u 
        where u.uid not in (select o.uid from orders o where o.productid = p.productid) and 
              u.gender = 'Female'
       ) as NumFemales     
from products p ;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a0e30/36) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Will this be better than my approach in performance ? Just curious

Comment: @Prdp . . . Actually, I don't know, the OP would need to test that.  This will make very good use of indexes on the obvious columns (although the `not in` might need to be replaced with `not exists` for best performance).

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get started with

```
SELECT p.productid, 
       p.productname, 
       COALESCE(total_maleusers, 0) - COALESCE(no_maleusers, 0) AS No_MaleUsers, 
       COALESCE(total_femaleusers, 0) - COALESCE(no_femaleusers, 0) AS No_FemaleUsers 
FROM   (SELECT p.productid, 
               p.productname, 
               total_maleusers, 
               total_femaleusers 
        FROM   (SELECT Count(CASE WHEN u.gender = 'Male' THEN 1 END) Total_MaleUsers, 
                       Count(CASE WHEN u.gender = 'Female' THEN 1 END) Total_FemaleUsers 
                FROM   users u) u 
               CROSS JOIN products p) p 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT p.productid, 
                              p.productname, 
                              Count(CASE WHEN u.gender = 'Male' THEN 1 END) No_MaleUsers, 
                              Count(CASE WHEN u.gender = 'Female' THEN 1 END) No_FemaleUsers 
                       FROM   products p 
                              JOIN orders o 
                                ON p.productid = o.productid 
                              JOIN users u 
                                ON u.uid = o.uid 
                       GROUP  BY p.productid, 
                                 p.productname) up 
                    ON p.productid = up.productid
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a0e30/29)

Comment: @Prdp -  I unable to access your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

We can obtain the result using the sub-queries and NOT EXISTS clause here

```
SELECT p.productid,
       p.productName,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   Users u
        WHERE  u.Gender = 'Male'
               AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                              FROM   Orders o
                              WHERE  o.productid = p.productid
                                     AND o.uid = u.uid)) No_MaleUsers,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   Users u
        WHERE  u.Gender = 'Female'
               AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                              FROM   Orders o
                              WHERE  o.productid = p.productid
                                     AND o.uid = u.uid)) No_FemaleUsers
FROM   Products p
```

SQL fiddle to refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a0e30/37